# Exeception query ID

Tags: php, mysql, exception, select

How can I make a query to select all *users* except the one with the *id* equal to 1 and 2?

```
SELECT *
FROM $viewUsuarios
WHERE login LIKE '%$busca%'
  OR nome LIKE '%$busca%'
  OR sobrenome LIKE '%$busca%'
  OR senhasErradas LIKE '%$busca%'
  OR ADMIN LIKE '%$busca%'
  OR ativo LIKE '%$busca%'
  OR verificado LIKE '%$busca%'
  OR termoUso LIKE '%$busca%'
  OR versaoTermoUso LIKE '%$busca%'
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $contadornInicioRegistros,
                      $limiteRegistros
```

Comment: WHERE id NOT IN (1,22)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will add AND
your query should look like this.

```
SELECT * FROM $viewUsuarios 
           WHERE login LIKE '%$busca%' OR 
                 nome LIKE '%$busca%' OR 
                 sobrenome LIKE '%$busca%' OR 
                 senhasErradas LIKE '%$busca%' OR 
                 admin LIKE '%$busca%' OR 
                 ativo LIKE '%$busca%' OR 
                 verificado LIKE '%$busca%' OR 
                 termoUso LIKE '%$busca%' OR 
                 versaoTermoUso LIKE '%$busca%' AND 
                 id>2 
           ORDER BY id ASC 
           LIMIT $contadornInicioRegistros, $limiteRegistros
```

I hope it can help.. ;)

Comment: That might potentially disregard ids 0 and below (if they existed).

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple != operator should suffice.

Ex. `"SELECT * from {$viewUsarios} WHERE id != 1 AND id != 2";`

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html